# RecyclerView with ExoPlayer is laggy

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have exoplayer inside recyclerview. It plays properly when view becomes visible. But my recyclerview  became laggy while scrolling.Any solution for this.

I have used below code for recyclerview

```
 binding.recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 binding.recycleView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
 binding.recycleView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 binding.recycleView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```

Comment: Are you creating a new instance of ExoPlayer for each RecyclerView item? If yes, try avoiding this and try to re-use ExoPlayer instance for all items if possible.

Comment: @KhawarRaza No i have one instance of ExoPlayer

Comment: Can you show me code of your adapter?